# How to convert ZULU timestamp to Europe/Paris time zone?

Tags: java, timezone, utc, java-time, datetime-conversion

I have a ZULU timestamp that I have to convert into Paris time zone.

```
ZULU 2022-11-04T06:10:08.606+00:00  --> Paris 2022-11-04T07:10:08.606+01:00
```

And have to take care of DST for example:
Summer time Hour  +2 hour
Winter time Hour   +1 hour

I have written the below code which is working as expected on the local but when deploy on the server (Paris) not working as expected.

```java
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ParisTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        // String date = "2022-05-31T23:30:12.209+00:00";
        String date = "2022-11-04T06:10:08.606+00:00";

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = dateFormat.parse(date).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
        ZonedDateTime of = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime, ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
        String hourDiff = of.toString().substring(of.toString().indexOf('+') + 1, of.toString().indexOf('+') + 3);
        String zonedDateTime = of.plusHours(Integer.valueOf(hourDiff)).toString();
        String newDatetime = zonedDateTime.substring(0, of.toString().indexOf('['));

        System.out.println(newDatetime);

        System.out.println(dateFormat.parse(newDatetime));
    }
}
```

Output

```
2022-11-04T07:10:08.606+01:00
Fri Nov 04 07:10:08 IST 2022
```

Comment: Why are you using `ZoneId.systemDefault()` for the timezone if it's supposed to be ZULU?

Comment: please stop using the old `Date`, `Calendar, `SimpleDateFormat` classes, use the classes from the `java.time` package (which you already are partially using) || BTW `ZonedDateTime` should be able to parse date/times formatted as `"2022-11-04T06:10:08.606+00:00"` directly, without needing any formatter (since it is already ISO 8601 formatted) ((and then use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.withZone()`))

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Mixing it with the modern classes in java.time is never a good idea. All you get is trouble and needless complication. Just stick to java.time.

Comment: When I run your code in Europe/Paris time zone, I get `2022-11-04T07:10:08.606+01:00` and `Fri Nov 04 07:10:08 CET 2022`, which both seem correct? What was your question again, please? Using your commented-out string I get `2022-06-01T01:30:12.209+02:00
Wed Jun 01 01:30:12 CEST 2022`, which seems correct too?

Comment: Also (1) parse the entire string; the offset, `+00:00`, is critical; (2) don’t do parsing nor time math “by hand”; leave all of it to the library classes.

Comment: @OleV.V. The out of code is what I expect when I deploy the code on the server located in France, it is not the same. I'm expecting +1 or +2 additional hours but somehow it adds the +6 or some time +8 and even notice that it changes the date also .

Comment: As I said, I have been unable to reproduce those +6. So it’s hard to help.

Comment: @OleV.V. Its random, not exactly +6 or +8 has been added to provided time. And the problem is occurring only when I deploy the code on the server which otherwise while testing on the local, everything is fine. I still doing my analysis why the random number is added.

Comment: And the @deHaar answer is also working as expected but the conversion of ZonedDateTime to Date create the problem again. Because entity column is defined as Date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly *switch* between zones and offsets using plain `java.time`, no legacy baggage necessary…

Here's how:

- your input example is an ISO-formatted datetime with an offset from UTC (of 0 hours and 0 minutes, so it is Zulu time respectively in UTC), which means you can parse it in one go to a `java.time.OffsetDateTime`
- an `OffsetDateTime` can be converted into a `ZonedDateTime`
- a `ZonedDateTime` can handle daylight saving time (DST)
- having a `ZonedDateTime` you can switch its `ZoneId`, which will respect DST, but keep the underlying instant

Please see the following example…

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // input example
    String date = "2022-11-04T06:10:08.606+00:00";
    // directly parse it to a java.time.OffsetDateTime
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(date);
    // make the UTC/Zulu datetime zoned
    ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.toZonedDateTime();
    // print it
    System.out.println(zdt);
    // switch the zone to the desired one
    ZonedDateTime zdtParis = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
    // print that, too
    System.out.println(zdtParis);
    // or print a coversion to OffsetDateTime without explicitly mentioning the zone
    System.out.println(zdtParis.toOffsetDateTime());
    // the same can be achieved keeping the ZonedDateTime but formatting it as OffsetDateTime
    System.out.println(zdtParis.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
}
```

The output of the above code is

```
2022-11-04T06:10:08.606Z
2022-11-04T07:10:08.606+01:00[Europe/Paris]
2022-11-04T07:10:08.606+01:00
2022-11-04T07:10:08.606+01:00
```

Try it with a datetime influenced by DST, you will see DST respected…
This is the output of the same code using the input value `"2022-05-31T23:30:12.209+00:00"`:

```
2022-05-31T23:30:12.209Z
2022-06-01T01:30:12.209+02:00[Europe/Paris]
2022-06-01T01:30:12.209+02:00
2022-06-01T01:30:12.209+02:00
```

Comment: Thanks. but now the problem is entity column is defined as Date. Will Date.from(zdtParis.toOffsetDateTime().toInstant()) is worked as same? And when I run it, the result is something "Wed Jun 01 05:00:12 IST 2022". Is it OK?

Comment: Or Date parse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
    .parse(zdtParis.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)); will work?

Comment: Don't think so, @AtulRai because the `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` prints an offset which your `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)` will not parse.

Comment: If you use the `Date.from(Instant)`, the value will be correctly converted. You'll be able to print the `Date` in the known format using a `SimpleDateFormat` resp. `toString()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked. From ZonedDatetime to Date, I used SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH) and it is working.

Answer (score 4):

Your string is already in the format recognized by [static] method `parse` in class `java.time.Instant`. Then you can convert that instant to a `ZonedDateTime` in the Paris time zone. Two lines of code:

```java
String date = "2022-11-04T06:10:08.606+00:00";
java.time.Instant inst = java.time.Instant.parse(date);
java.time.ZonedDateTime zdt = inst.atZone(java.time.ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
```

It will also take into consideration changes for summer time and non-summer time.

```
ZULU : 2022-11-04T06:10:08.606Z
Paris: 2022-11-04T07:10:08.606+01:00[Europe/Paris]
```

Comment: This simple and recommended solution works since Java 12 (up to Java 11 `Instant.parse()` did not accept the offset in `+00:00` format).

Comment: Yes, it throws Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-11-04T06:10:08.606+00:00' could not be parsed at index 23

Comment: I'm using JDK 8